# Best PHP driver/client for Cassandra 2.1 and CQL 3

Tags: php, pdo, cassandra, webdriver

I am new to using Cassandra. Any help is greatly appreciated.

I am wondering what the best PHP(PHP5.5.9) driver for Cassandra 2.1 and CQL3 is. I have looked at some of the drivers listed here
http://planetcassandra.org/client-drivers-tools/#PHP but I can't decide which driver is the best.

Is it better to use a driver that depends on PDO?

Also I read that Thrift is being declared legacy, so I don't know whether I should use the drivers based on Thrift.

So I'm wondering which driver is the best to use and why? Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: We work in our company on java and .net and we are using extensively datastax driver. I do not have experience with PHP one but recently they announced that they released alpha version, I can tell you that their driver for java is best, so you check it out. https://github.com/datastax/php-driver

Comment: Yeah I've seen that one but it's a wrapper for the C/C++ driver. Is it better to use that or go with something that uses PDO such as https://github.com/Orange-OpenSource/YACassandraPDO. Or is it better to go with the binary protocal here http://evseevnn.github.io/php-cassandra-binary/ ?

Comment: I do not have PHP experience, nor C/C++, I was mentioning just that datastax does it good based on java and .NET experience